# Fetch custom field data from order and send to gravity form entry

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

Just wondering if anyone would have the solution to my snippet not working.

I would like to fetch the value of the two custom fields from the order and then update a gravity form entry. I think the issue is in the fetching of the order info.
Please help!

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete','sendtoformentry');
function sendtoformentry($order_id) {
         
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );         
    $order_id = $order->get_order_number();   
    $fieldnumber($order_id, 'paymentnumber', true);
    $entrynumber($order_id, 'bookingnumber', true);
    GFAPI::update_entry_field( rgar( $entrynumber, 'id' ), $fieldnumber, 'paid' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'sendtoformentry', 10, 2);

function sendtoformentry($order_id, $transaction_id) {

    $fieldnumber = get_post_meta($order_id, 'paymentnumber', true);
    $entrynumber = get_post_meta($order_id, 'bookingnumber', true);
    GFAPI::update_entry_field(rgar($entrynumber, 'id'), $fieldnumber, 'paid');
}
```

The hook inside woocommerce core is like `do_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', $this->get_id(), $transaction_id );`

Comment: Unfortunately this has not worked for me either.

Comment: Make sure the meta key "paymentnumber" is correct.

Comment: Definitely is 'paymentnumber'

Comment: Do you think i need to call on the gravity forms data?

Comment: Just add `error_log("paynumcheck====". $fieldnumber);` and check the log if its writing the value of the meta

Comment: I used this in a function and it didnt work either.   $entrynumber='7722'; GFAPI::update_entry_field(rgar($entrynumber, 'id'), '57', 'paid');

Comment: Then you have to look for if the class `"GFAPI"` is loaded in the context.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed' instead.  Also, try using the GFAPI method below:

```
//add order number to gravity forms
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'sendtoformentry' );
function sendtoformentry( $order_id ) {
    $fieldnumber = get_post_meta($order_id, 'paymentnumber', true);
    $entrynumber = get_post_meta($order_id, 'bookingnumber', true);
    $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entrynumber );
    if(GFAPI::entry_exists( $entry ) && !empty($fieldnumber)){
      $entry[$fieldnumber] = 'paid';
      $result = GFAPI::update_entry( $entry );
    }
    return;        
};
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Comment: Do you have access to your MYSQL database?  If so, can you confirm that the post meta 'paymentnumber' and 'bookingnumber' are returning what you need?  Maybe you should make a fake gravity form entry and then replace $entrynumber with that id.  Replace $fieldnumber with '57'. If that works you know the issue is probably with the post_meta. Otherwise, try add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'sendtoformentry' ) instead of 'woocommerce_payment_complete; ;

Comment: This needs to be able to trigger from the backend also - when an order is marked complete manually. The meta is being stored ok

Comment: Weird Jessinca, I use this code on my website and it's working. Did you try the  add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'sendtoformentry' )?  Any error log clues?

Comment: Yes I tried that